# Newton Raphson convergence: a convex function over a convex cone

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, newton-raphson

Similar to the Newton Raphson algorithm that has a (global) convergence property when we minimize a (strictly) convex function over Euclidean space (based on the second order Taylor serise expansion with a geometric or any other property), can we say that it also has a convergence property by replacing Euclidean space with a convex cone?

Comment: You need a barrier function, as the Newton step might lead to the outside of the cone. But otherwise, it is pretty standard.